# How to add or create zip file on Amazon S3 Bucket?

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

How to add/create zip from amazon s3 bucket text file? or How to create zip on amazon s3 bucket?

I am using AWS SDK for PHP.

```
   try {
       $src = "file.txt";
       $target = "file.zip";// Add file.txt to file.zip
       $Bucket = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
       $zip = new ZipArchive();
       if ($zip->open(("s3://{$Bucket}/{$target}"), ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) != TRUE) {
           return false;
       }
       $zip->addFile("s3://{$Bucket}/{$src}");
       $zip->close();
       return true;
   }
   catch (Exception $e) {
       return $e->getMessage();
   }
```

My code is doesn't working, display only blank output with no error.

Comment: `s3` is not a standard protocol. You need to access it from the CLI... or I'd think. I use `exec` and have bucket permissions set for the server. `My code is doesn't working` isn't much to work with. Can you provide more detail about what fails, do you get error messages?

Comment: Yes if i am using fopen("s3://{$Bucket}/{$src}") it's working. but above code just display blank output with no error.

Comment: I've never used `fopen` with an `s3` protocol before, has that worked for your before? I think you could use the `http` e.g. `http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com`

Comment: @user3783243 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html

Comment: I am using file releated function with s3 and it's working good. And it's not working with http, I have checked http url instend of "s3://{$Bucket}/{$src}".

Comment: @Brad Oh.. this looks very useful. Thanks

Comment: Hai, did you get any solution for this problem?